# How to limit the "resident set size" per user on Linux

Tags: linux

Normally this can be accomplished by "ulimit -m" but on Linux (at least on Centos5) "man bash" says "-m The maximum resident set size (has no effect on Linux)".

So since "ulimit -m" has no effect on Linux is there another way to limit the resident set size per user?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cgroups, limit memory per user](https://serverfault.com/questions/719994/cgroups-limit-memory-per-user)

Answer (score 2):

Limiting the total vmem size (-v) is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks but we actually want to limit the resident set size, not the virtual memory size.

Comment: Well .. you can't, according to the documentation; the kernel ignores it. Why do you want to do this, and what behaviour do you expect when processes go over their RSS limit?

Answer (score 1):

`ulimit -m` **never** limited RSS *per user*.

In the past (Linux 2.4.x, x < 30), `ulimit -m` affected the RSS **per process**.  And even then, it was advice to the memory manager, not a hard limit.  (See the `RLIMIT_RSS` section of `man setrlimit`.)

Similarly, `ulimit -v` **does not** impose *per user* limits.  It imposes **per process** limits.

If you want to impose *per user* limits on Linux, I recommend considering `cgroups`.