# Cgroups, limit memory per user

Tags: cgroup

Is it possible to limit memory usage per user not per group?

This is my config ...

**/etc/cgconfig.conf**

```
mount {
    cpu     = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
    memory  = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
}
group small {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares="100";
        }
        cpuacct {
                cpuacct.usage="0";
        }
        memory {
                memory.limit_in_bytes="200M";
                memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="200M";
        }
}
```

**/etc/cgrules.conf**

```
@guests      cpu,cpuacct,memory      small
user1        cpu,cpuacct,memory      small
user2        cpu,cpuacct,memory      small
```

Right now i see only one option to create group small1 and link user1 to that group, then user2 to small2 and so on, like this:

**/etc/cgconfig.conf**

```
group small1 {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares="100";
...
group small2 {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares="100";
...
```

**/etc/cgrules.conf**

```
user1        cpu,cpuacct,memory      small1
user2        cpu,cpuacct,memory      small2
```

Does anybody know better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to limit memory usage per user not per group?

It is possible with [templates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-Moving_a_Process_to_a_Control_Group.html)

> Rules specified in /etc/cgrules.conf can be linked to templates
>   configured either in the /etc/cgconfig.conf file or in configuration
>   files stored in the /etc/cgconfig.d/ directory, allowing for flexible
>   cgroup assignment and creation.