# systemd, per-user cpu and/or memory limits

Tags: systemd, user-management, resource-management, limits

There is similar question: [Cgroups, limit memory per user](https://serverfault.com/q/719994/436080), but the solution doesn't work in "modern" systems, where cgroups hierarchy is 
managed by systemd.

Straightforward solution — templating user-UID.slice — won't work, because it is not supported, see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2556.

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect — manage CPU and/or memory resources on a per-user basis?

**UPD**: I'll keep my solution for the sake of history, but `systemctl set-property` should be called at login time, using `pam_exec`, see https://github.com/hashbang/shell-etc/pull/183. In this approach, there is no time window between the user's login and setting of limits.

**My solution**. [Interface `org.freedesktop.login1.Manage` of `/org/freedesktop/login1` object](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/#themanagerobject) emits `UserNew(u uid, o object_path)` signal. I've written a simple daemon which listens to the signal and every time it is emitted set `CPUAccounting=true` for just-logged-in-user's slice.

Comment: I'm not very fond on cgroups, I have sucesfully configured with cgconfig/crules, but is not the right way for per-user limits. It's not clear to me what I need to install and edit (limits.sh ?) in Ubuntu 20, in order to implement the systemctl solution. Do you have any tip/link/wlakthru, can you elaborate? Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPD**: I'll keep my solution for the sake of history, but `systemctl set-property` should be called at login time, using `pam_exec`, see https://github.com/hashbang/shell-etc/pull/183. In this approach, there is no time window between the user's login and setting of limits.

**Old solution**

Here is a very simple script which does the job

```
#!/bin/bash

STATE=1 # 1 -- waiting for signal; 2 -- reading UID

dbus-monitor --system "interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager,member=UserNew" |
while read line
do
    case $STATE in
    1) [[ $line =~ member=UserNew ]] && STATE=2 ;;
    2) read dbus_type ID <<< $line
       systemctl set-property user-$ID.slice CPUAccounting=true
       STATE=1
    ;;
    esac
done
```

It can be easily extended to support per-user memory limits.

Tested it on a VM with 2 CPUs and 2 users. The first user run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` command and the second one run only one instance of `dd`. Without this script running, each instance of `dd` used around 70% of CPU.

Then I started the script, relogged users, and starded `dd` commands again. This time two `dd` processes of the first user took only 50% of CPU each and the process of the second user took 100% of CPU. Also, `systemd-cgtop` showed, that `/user.slice/user-UID1.slice` and `/user.slice/user-UID2.slice` take 100% of CPU time each, but the first  slice has 6 tasks and the second one only 5 tasks.

When I kill `dd` task of the second user, the first user starts consuming 200% of CPU time. So, we have fair resource allocation without artificial restrictions like "each user may use only one core".

Answer (score 10):

Starting with systemd v239, you can use drop-ins
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/5396624506e155c4bc10c0ee65b939600860ab67

```
# mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/50-memory.conf << EOF
[Slice]
MemoryMax=1G
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: on my Ubuntu 20 server, what should I need to install in order to this to work well? Shoudl I also activate CPU accounting somewhere? I tried by simply creating this file (and perdormed daemon-reload) but my user is still able to execute tress-ng --vm-bytes 5000000000 -m 1 with no errors... I think I miss something in the way sustemd or cgroup work. Any tip is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps It's my fault, it is working, stress-ng respects the max amount of memory I set. (I expected an error)

Comment: Another sub-question, I configured user-slice.d as suggested (for all user) and forced a different cgroup setting for user-1000.slide.d (more resources), it seems to work well. It looks like specific cgroup settings for user overrides more general user-* configs. Is this right? Or may there be subtle problems that my tests have not highlighted?

Comment: Note that your distribution may require `MemoryAccounting=true` in addition to `MemoryMax=1G`. I'm pretty sure that older versions of `systemd` were not smart enough to automatically turn on memory accounting if `MemoryMax` was used alone.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you mentioned is still open, but this works for me.

```
sudo systemctl edit --force user-1234.slice
```

Then type and save this:

```
[Slice]
CPUQuota=10%
```

I'm not sure why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility of achieving CPU or memory limitations through cgroups is to use `libpam-cgroup`, which can select a profile at login from `/etc/cgconfig.conf`. A commonly seen example is the following:

```
group limited {
   cpu {
     cpu.cfs_period_us = "1000000";
     cpu.cfs_quota_us = "500000";
   }
   memory {
      memory.limit_in_bytes = "1G";
      memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = "1G";
   }
}
```

This creates an `interactive` group limiting resources to 1 GB memory and 50% of a CPU core (500 ms per second of total CPU time). Then the `/etc/cgrules.conf` file can be set to put specific group or users under this group:

```
root       cpu,memory      /
@nolimits  cpu,memory      /
*          cpu,memory      /limited
```

In this case, `root` and everybody belonging to the `nolimits` group get the default (unlimited) cgroup, while all other users will be limited by the policy set above.

The first matching line is used, therefore it is possible to have a default unlimited policy while limiting a specific user or group like:

```
spam       cpu,memory      /limited
*          cpu,memory      /
```

In this case we are limiting the `spam` user, and no one else.

For this to work, `pam_cgroup.so` has to be enabled, for example in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` PAM profile:

```
session    optional     pam_cgroup.so
```

Finally, the `cgrules.conf` file has to be parsed at boot. This can be achieved with a simple systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load cgroup profiles

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This can be saved for example to `/etc/systemd/system/loadcg.service` and then enabled with `systemctl enable loadcg`.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu I needed to increase the `TasksMax` for a single user, the CI service user (UID 2000) that runs all of my group's tests, from the default limit of 10813 to something higher. I checked the old limit with `sudo systemctl status user-2000.slice`, then set a new limit by typing `sudo systemctl edit --force user-2000.slice` and entering:

```
[Slice]
TasksMax=50000
```

That updates the limit and creates the file `/etc/systemd/system/user-2000.slice.d/override.conf` which contains the above settings. I added the file to my Ansible playbooks and now it gets deployed to all of our machines so the limit stays set even if we rebuild a server.